# SQLServer try catch performance

Tags: sql-server, try-catch

Has anyone found any performance boost/tradoff of using BEGIN TRY..END TRY in sql server 2008, vs the old IF @@ERROR <> 0?  Just curious to know if there are performance penalties or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an old question, but in 2012 Aaron Bertrand wrote a detailed article [Performance impact of different error handling techniques](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/error-handling) where he compared few approaches for dealing with exceptions in SQL Server and I thought it is worth mentioning it here.

He says, that the primary approaches people use to deal with exceptions are:

> - Just let the engine handle it, and bubble any exception back to the caller.
> - Use `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `ROLLBACK` if `@@ERROR <> 0`.
> - Use `TRY/CATCH` with `ROLLBACK` in the `CATCH` block (SQL Server 2005+).
>
> And many take the approach that they should check if they're going to
>   incur the violation first, since it seems cleaner to handle the
>   duplicate yourself than to force the engine to do it.

His conclusions are:

> If we think we are going to have a high rate of failure, or have no
>   idea what our potential failure rate will be, then checking first to
>   avoid violations in the engine is going to be tremendously worth our
>   while. Even in the case where we have a successful insert every time,
>   the cost of checking first is marginal and easily justified by the
>   potential cost of handling errors later (unless your anticipated
>   failure rate is exactly 0%).

This is the chart from the article:

[image: summary]

```
CheckInsert    |  Checks `IF EXISTS` first  |  Simple `INSERT`
CheckRollback  |  Checks `IF EXISTS` first  |  Use `IF @@ERROR <> 0`
CheckTryCatch  |  Checks `IF EXISTS` first  |  Use `TRY CATCH`
JustInsert     |                            |  Simple `INSERT`
JustRollback   |                            |  Use `IF @@ERROR <> 0`
JustTryCatch   |                            |  Use `TRY CATCH`
```

Comment: Hey there. I am unsure as to what your main point is. If you are suggesting that in addition to TRY...CATCH people also do checks first, then that is irrelevant as it pertains to all possible scenarios, and should be obvious, at least to DB professionals, that doing a simple read is less work than writing to the log and then having to do more work to manage the ROLLBACK. If you are saying to only do the check and not use TRY...CATCH, then that is a dangerous misunderstanding of a test that doesn't speak to why we use exception handling in the first place.

Comment: @srutzky, that article compares various variants, not just those asked in this question. You can see on the chart performance of `TRY ... CATCH` vs `IF @@ERROR <> 0`. In case with many rollbacks `TRY...CATCH` is much better, not worse as you thought.

Comment: That article is mostly pointless. It really only counters the absurd scenario of not doing pre-validation. So ignore the "Just*" tests. How many operations are a single row action? Who would allow the error to happen in set-based approaches, when the rollback can take minutes? And the test doesn't cover the real usage of `TRY...CATCH` by placing the `IF EXISTS` inside of it. The "All Fail" scenario is interesting to note but impractical because it would never happen, and it skips all 3 of the options so is not comparing them. That shows `TRY...CATCH` being 3rd in the 6 tests that relate here.

Comment: And coming in last (even more so if testing the more likely scenario of placing the `IF EXISTS` inside of the `TRY...CATCH`) is ok because pre-validation isn't the primary reason to do error handling, which is the problem with that article. We use error handling because we cannot pre-validate all possible errors. There can be permissions errors, deadlocks, etc. We use TRY...CATCH because it is the best means of controlling the process when unpredictable errors happen, _especially_ within nested scenarios. Please see my answer here to see what I mean: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/93265/30859

Answer (score 4):

Since the database disk hit issues are identical, there should be no appreciable performance issues.

Comment: The performance of `TRY ... CATCH` and `IF @@ERROR <> 0` is somewhat different. But, more importantly, there is a significant difference if you try to prevent the error in the first place. Aaron Bertrand has shown it in a detailed article [Performance impact of different error handling techniques](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/error-handling). I put in the answer below the summary of his findings.

Answer (score 3):

Since SQL 2005, you should try to use the TRY CATCH way to handle the exceptions or logging the errors. It is considered as best practice. There should have no major performance hit by using it.

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    -- SQL 
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK
    SELECT
        ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        ERROR_NUMBER() -- etc
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 2):

Forget performance, it's a damn sight safer, better and more predicatable.

However, using @@ERROR usually requires a GOTO and/or lots of IF statements to manage it correctly so I'd guess there may be a tiny boost in TRY..CATCH.

Comment: Agreed. Performance is not the primary concern here given how much better of a construct the T-SQL `TRY`/ `CATCH` is over testing for `@@ERROR` after each statement. While there is a slight performance hit for using `TRY`/ `CATCH`, it is an acceptable price to pay given the other benefits.

Comment: @srutzky, Still, if you are after the performance, be aware, that performance of `TRY ... CATCH` and `IF @@ERROR <> 0` is somewhat different. But, more importantly, there is a significant difference if you try to prevent the error in the first place. Aaron Bertrand has shown it in a detailed article [Performance impact of different error handling techniques](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/error-handling). I put in the answer below the summary of his findings.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov That article isn't relevant to this Question. Of course there is significant savings in avoiding the need to roll-back. That is assumed and shouldn't need to be stated. But you still need error handling, and `TRY...CATCH` is far better than testing `@@ERROR <> 0`, even if `TRY...CATCH` is a tiny bit slower.

Answer (score 1):

THe performance of TRY ... CATCH is most likely a bit more when there are no errors. On the other hand, it will be faster in many cases where there is an error.

But, you should not code strictly for performance anyway. And, the overhead, if any, is going to be rather small, so I would not trade off the safer syntax for performance in this instance.

In addition, the Try ... Catch makes code a bit easier to maintain, especially if your SQL dev team has not been around SQL Server very long, which unfortunately, happens a bit too often. I imagine this will be more the case a few years from now.

Comment: good explanation @Gregory. I looking this type of answer that if nothing use vs try....catch, then also impact come or not.

Answer (score -3):

- [Speed Test: Try / Catch Block](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SpeedTestTryCatch.aspx)
- [Do try...catch blocks hurt runtime
  performance?](http://www.programmersheaven.com/user/pheaven/blog/175-Do-trycatch-blocks-hurt-runtime-performance/)

Comment: He asked specifically about SQL Server; C# articles aren't relevant here.